TOC spans over 3 pages - Able to add TOC(Continued) to the second page but third page doesnt start with TOC(Continued)
I'm trying to fix the Table of Contents (TOC) in my thesis. After TOC title the list goes on and in total it takes 3 pages to list all content. I need to add TOC (Continued) title to every additional page.
I was able to add TOC (Continued) to second page, but third page still misses to have TOC (Continued) title. I need help.
Here's the code in the main tex file:
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\contheading}{%
    \afterpage{{\normalfont\bfseries\centering
            TABLE OF CONTENTS (CONTINUED)\par\bigskip}
            \vspace{30pt}
           \noindent \quad \hfill \underline{\textbf{Page}}\\[12pt]
        }}

\begin{center}
\addtocontents{toc}{\contheading}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tableofcontents %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{center}

There's also a part from the cls file:
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \begin{center}
   % \vspace*{-0.4cm}
    %\contentsname\\
    \textbf{TABLE OF CONTENTS} \\
    \vspace{30pt}
    \end{center}
   \noindent \quad \hfill \underline{\textbf{Page}}\\[12pt]
    \@starttoc{toc}

    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }

Thank you.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.
